# .htaccess query regrading a sub-directory in URL and 404 error

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site installed on domain www.mydomain.com/alpha/ [**directory can not be changed now**]

Problem 1:
Redirect request to www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/alpha/

(once redirection takes place other links also should not show alpha in URL)

Problem 2:
Other links on my site have alpha in URL. Is there a way to remove this alpha even before user clicks on any link.

Problem 3:
I have another site hosted at www.mydomain.com/alpha2/ this should not be affected.
I put following .htaccess and this site is throwing 404 error.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^alpha/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /alpha/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the directory on your site would have better performance. If you cannot do that, then you can try adding the following to the .htaccess in the root dir of your site.

It assumes that each site (alpha and alpha2) are self contained i.e. all the resources (css, js etc) are in the alpha and alpha2 directories respectively. If this is not true, then the rules may need adjusting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

### first 301 redirect all /alpha requests to without alpha
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /alpha(/[^\ ]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,L]

### next rewrite all requests to alpha
#prevent internal redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
#exclude alpha2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/alpha2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ alpha%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This should solve questions 1,3.

> Is there a way to remove this alpha even before user clicks on any link.

Its more involved, but, yes, you can write your own [filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html).